# Hosting an R plumber API using docker

Tags: r, docker, plumber

I work on a windows laptop and want to host an API of mine that I made in R (using plumber package) using docker desktop for windows.
The tutorial found [here](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/hosting.html) gives an example of running a pre-installed plumber code using this command: `docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 rstudio/plumber`. This hosts the API that is present in the given location: "C:\Users\sidmh\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\plumber\examples\04-mean-sum\plumber.R"
However, I want to host an API present in this location: "C:\Users\sidmh\Documents\Nutri\plumber.R"
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to adapt (from the `plumber` documentation) the `Dockerfile` to get your custom `my_plumber_api.R` script stored in the 'app' folder with something along :

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rstudio/plumber

# list all the needed packages here in the same fashion
RUN R -e "install.packages('broom')"

# to launch your docker container
CMD ["/app/my_plumber_api.R"]
```

Then you will need to **build** (and **tag** for convenience) the docker image before being able to **run** it with :

```
$ cd projet_folder
$ docker build -t my_plumber_api .
$ docker run -p 8000:8000 my_plumber_api
```

You should check the Docker documentation for specifics (choose the exposed port, ...).